# Format date with datetime picker to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I am using DateTime picker from material.

But I want to have the format like this:

2021-02-15 23:59:59

So I try it like this:

```
export const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MMM DD, YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-editor',
  templateUrl: './widget-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-editor.component.css'],
  providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS}]
})
```

and template looks like this:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="start" class="editor-label col-sm-4"><strong> Time start:</strong></label>

                <input [(ngModel)]="start" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" class="date"  id="start" value="start"  matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker">
                <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>


                <span class="ml-2" (click)= "reOpenCalender()">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faCalendarAlt" size="1x"    #picker [styles]="{'color': '#B7B7B7'}"
                      ></fa-icon>
                </span>
            </div>
```

But this doesn't work, it still shows this:

```
2/25/2021, 16:32:52
```

So what I have to change?

I try it like this:

```
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat === 'input') {
      let day: string = date.getDate().toString();
      day = +day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
      let month: string = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
      month = +month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
    return date.toDateString();
  }
}
export const APP_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' },
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
    },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
  }
};
```

But I don't use a date picker, But I am using: DateTime picker:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

and then it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use a Date pipe. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: ? But I don't have a property. How to do it in this example?

Comment: You can a get UNIX timestamp with the date picker and convert it with Date Pipe to any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it yourself by putting together the day, month, and year. I'm not sure if this code is exactly what you want but you could do something similar.

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate() + "/" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + today.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use thisone for your date format.
DateFormat :-  this.currentDate = `${this.currDate.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')}-${(this.currDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${this.currDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${this.currDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${this.currDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${this.currDate.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`

Comment: But how to use this?